# Sorting ArrayList by sting length in java

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I have an ArrayList

```
ArrayList<String[]> matches = new ArrayList<String[]>();

Collections.sort(matches, new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String word1, String word2) {
        return word2.length() - word1.length();
        }
    });
```

I want to sort this ArrayList by the length of the strings in the ArrayList. I want the list to be in descending order.

```
Input = ace, a, apple, cord

Output = apple, cord, ace, a
```

Comment: `ace, a, apple, cord` is just `ArrayList<String>`, **NOT** `ArrayList<String[]>`.

Comment: Please explain the steps that you have taken so far in order to solve this problem.

Comment: Where is your attempt at the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You probably meant `List<String>`, not `List<String[]>` as the input.
2. In order to sort your list you need to use `java.util.Collections.sort` method with custom comparator that compares elements by length:

   ```
   List<String> list = Arrays.asList(
           "ace", "a", "apple", "cord"
   );

   Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<String>() {
       @Override
       public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
           return o2.length() - o1.length();
       }
   });

   System.out.println(list);
   ```

Answer (score 1):

This works with Java 8.

```
Collections.sort(dictionary, (a, b)->Integer.compare(a.length(), b.length()));
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to implement a comparator, like that:

```
class stringLengthComparator implements Comparator<String> {
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        if (o1.length() > o2.length()) {
            return 1;
        } else if (o1.length() < o2.length()) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

and then you just sort your ArrayList like that:

```
Collections.sort(matches, new stringLengthComparator());
```

Comment: `Collections.sort`,  not `Arrays.sort`

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly, how you are going to do your program using ArrayList. Make sure you import the proper java.util classes.

```
    public static void main(String args[])
{
    String matches[] = {"ace", "a", "apple", "cord"};
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    Collections.addAll(list, matches);
    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<String>(){
        public int compare(String o1, String o2)
        {
            return o1.length() - o2.length();
        }
    });

    Collections.reverse(list);
    System.out.println(list);
}

Input: "ace", "a", "apple", "cord"
Output: [apple, cord, ace, a]
```

P.S. This has been tested and it works exactly the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

Since Java 8 you can directly use the method `List.sort()`:

```
List<String> stringList = Arrays.asList("ace", "a", "apple", "cord");
stringList.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(String::length).reversed());
```

`stringList` will be ordered in descending order:

```
apple, cord, ace, a
```